# PhpMyAdmin Error: Mismatch Token

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've just recently been getting an error in my local installation on installed on apache on xampp. I'm running v4.0.5 of phpmyadmin. The error description is Error: Mismatch Token.

Has anyone else experienced this an found a fix for it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

Find the XAMPP php.ini file and uncomment by removing the semi-colon:

```
session.save_path ="/tmp"
```

Then restart apache.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Solved it by changing following:

```
$token_mismatch = true;
```

to

```
$token_mismatch = false;
```

in [\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php](http://%5Cxampp%5CphpMyAdmin%5Clibraries%5Ccommon.inc.php)

Answer (score 2):

Did you change anything in your apache server config files?

if not,

open browser, clear all history(ctrl+shift+del), and restart browser, go to phpmyadmin page.

it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I too came across a same issue. I tried many ways, like clearing cache, managing more space for my /tmp directory. But at last I solved this issue by removing the unwanted files from my server & managing free space on my server.

You can check here how I have done that. **[Error: Token Mismatch PhpMyAdmin Cpanel Solved](http://www.allinformer.com/error-token-mismatch-error-in-phpmyadmin/)**

Answer (score 0):

Changing session.save_path in php.ini to "/tmp" worked for me, RedHat6.

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra "/" in my browser path.
Removed that an it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, try the following:

```
Delete cookies from 127.0.0.1.
Try to reproduce the problem in a different browser.
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

This error may appear if your website has a Content-Security-Policy header that is too restrictive.

This header caused the "Mismatch token" error for me:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

By adding `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` the error disappeared:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

More info: https://content-security-policy.com/