# phpmyadmin - token mismatch

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I dont know what happen, did not make any configuration. Previously works totally fine, after restart my computer, the error appears. I tried the solution from [here](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/fix-token-mismatch-error-phpmyadmin/) but it did not solve the problem.

Tried `# chmod 755 /home/username/tmp` but did not work as well.

[image]

[image: Disk Space]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Result in different browser ?

Comment: I tried using safari, but getting the same error.

Comment: but i am able to access to my files `http://localhost/getStore.php`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358867/phpmyadmin-error-mismatch-token?rq=1

Comment: Hi, i already tried all the answer from that post, but it does not work for me:(

Answer (score -1):

clear cookies of browser and login it again it will clear that issue

Comment: Hi, I clear the cookies on my chrome and restart the server again, but It does not work.